# Comment hyperlinks in meta are indistinguishable from regular text

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Very minor design problem, but as shown below links within comments on meta are the same color as normal text.

Here is how they look on meta:

[image: screenshot of a meta comment with a link]

And here is how the look on main:

[image: screenshot of a main comment with a link]

Comment: This is a comment [with a hyperlink](http://meta.graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/909/8708 "TEST COMMENT DO NOT CLICK!!!")

Comment: This is [a](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/227520/my-dog-ate-my-unicoins?rq=1) comment with one or possibly more top secret h[id](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/4999/how-can-i-tell-if-a-corpse-is-safe-to-eat)den hyperlinks to test if this sto[p](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162735/when-you-kill-someone-do-you-get-his-hat)s people [from](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/how-do-i-get-my-cat-to-wear-a-tuxedo-for-several-hours) spotting hyperlink[s](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/159144/how-can-i-kill-puppies-without-consequences)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed, it will be live  after our next production build.